# Share a value across Tornado Websockets server

Tags: python, web-services, tornado

I have a basic websocket server using Tornado framework in python. I want to share a value between the server functions:

```
class EchoWebSocket(websocket.WebSocketHandler):

    def check_origin(self, origin):
        return True
    def open(self):
        print ("connection opened")
    def on_close(self):
        tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().stop()
        print ("connection closed")
    def on_message(self,message):
        print (message)

def Main():
    application = tornado.web.Application([(r"/", EchoWebSocket),])
    application.listen(9000)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main()
```

I tried to create a global object from a class like this:

```
class operate:
    state = "mutual"

    def __init__(self):
        self.state = 'mutual'

    def play(self):
        self.state = 'play'

    def pause(self):
        self.state = 'pause'

    def getStatus(self):
        return self.state
```

and call a global object, guessing that since the object is global it will be the same not creating a new one every message:

```
def open(self):
    global objectTV
    objectTV = operate()
    objectTV.play()
.
.
.
.
 def on_message(self,message):
        global objectTV
        objectTV = operate()
        print(objectTV.getStatus())
```

But it always print 'mutual'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the method `on_message()`, every time a new message arrives, you're instantiating `objectTV` again and again at `objectTv = operate()`. The new instance of `operate` class has the initial state set to `'mutual'`, that is why it's printing `'mutual'`.

A simple fix would be to remove `objectTV = operate()` line from `on_message()` and it should work like you want it to.

But read some answers on this question: [Why are global variables evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19158339/1925257).

So, the better approach to solve your problem would be to set a local attribute on the handler instance instead:

```
class EchoWebSocket(websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    ...
    def open(self):
        self.objectTV = operate()
        self.objectTV.play()

    def on_message(self, message):
        print(self.objectTV.getStatus()) # -> 'play'
```

Comment: I made a mistake in the question, This way is working based on my question. But what I really need is an object that is visible while the socket is opened and exchanging messages. I have ( if, else ) in 'on_message', I check the messages coming from the client. based on the client messages I want to update the object.  This way does not work for what I need because on each message sent from the client I think Tornado opens a new thread for it. Do you have any idea how to share that object across the messages?

Comment: @Hussein Do you want to share the same object across different clients? You can remove this line - `self.objectTV = operate()` from the `open()` method and set `objectTV = operate()` on the `EchoWebSocket` class directly as a class attribute. The new clients who connect will share the same object. If I completely missed what you meant, feel free to update your question with some more details about your problem or code, I'll update my answer.